# How to restore PostgreSQL database from version 9.6 to 10.25 with all sequences?

Tags: postgresql, odoo-10

After restoring the database in PostgreSQL from version `9.6 to 10.25` it shows an error about

> UndefinedTable: relation "purchase_request_id_seq" does not exist LINE
> 1: ...uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('purchase_...

how can I restore this database from a lower version to a higher version?

I am using PostgreSQL 10.25 and the restored database is from 9.6 in .zip file

Comment: How did you create the backup? And how do you try to restore?

Comment: `pg_dump` **will** include all sequences. But as you are restoring from a "zip file" I assume you did not use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` which would have been the correct way to do this.

Comment: There is no 10.25.  The highest bug-fix release of 10 is currently 10.15.

Comment: I also try to restore from the backend using pg_dump, pg_restore command. but still all sequences not restore.  also, I try the same backup file on the same version of postgres and it install properly.

Comment: I got the solution to restore the database from higher version to a lower version.
if sequence error occurs during restore the database just remove As integer from dump.sql file and restore it will solve the sequence error.

For Example:
CREATE SEQUENCE public.project_config_settings_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

Remove AS integer
    CREATE SEQUENCE public.project_config_settings_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;